# Retrofit + Dagger + Different Endpoints

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger

In my app I use Retrofit and pass an instance of ApiClient in appropriate place via Dagger. I've read that `RestAdapter.Builder.build()` and `adapter.create(Class class)` are very expensive. So I annotate the provide method as @Singleton.

Here is abstract code:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
ApiClient provideRestClient() {
  ...
  return adapter.create(ApiClient.class)
}
```

Everything worked great, but now I need to switch between several subdomains. I.e. from http://subdomain1.domain.com to http://subdomain2.domain.com for example.

Can I change an endpoint in runtime? Or I shouldn't use Retrofit in this case...

Comment: Why you need to use subdomains? Maybe it will be better to have different paths, not subdomains. In case of subdomains I guess you will need to create different Retrofit services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`Endpoint`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Endpoint.html) class:

> Callers should always consult the instance for the latest values rather than caching the returned values.

This means you can change the value that you return from `getUrl()` in your own `Endpoint` implementation class based on the server you wish to connect to.